# Clone HDD to ssd

Tags: upgrade

To begin with I'm looking to install a ssd in my desktop running Ubuntu 22.04.
In simple layman's terms how do I clone the contents of the HDD to the SSD.
When I say simple I mean just that, don't suppose I know anything about using the terminal etc.
Looking forward to some plain English answers.

Comment: How are you backing up your install now? I would suggest just doing new clean install, and restoring from your normal backup. Becomes good test of your backup as you still have original drive in case something is missing. Also if you clone drive, you cannot boot with both old & new drives connected. Duplicate UUIDs are not allowed. Is SSD same size or larger that HDD?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this fairly simple with Gparted. You are able to download an ISO that you can use with a USB as boot media. Then having both the SSD and HDD connected, and you can copy paste.

Here is a better written guide on how to with pictures: https://www.diskpart.com/clone/clone-partition-gparted-7201.html